# Rog Zenith ii Extreme won't turn on

Tags: memory, cpu, bios, motherboard, power-supply

I'm building a deep learning system for my company and my current build is:

- Rog Zenith ii Extreme
- 2 * Aorus RTX 3090
- 256 GB  Kingston Fury 2666MHz
- EVGA Supernova 1600W
- AMD 3960 threadripper

Along with a liquid CPU cooler and storage. When I try turning the PC on, nothing happens, only the yellow BIOS light on the motherboard turns on. The small LCD screen does not turn on and the start button does not light up, only the yellow BIOS light underneath the RAM, see attached image.

Up close photo of bios light

[image: Up close photo of bios light]

System

[image: System]

I've tested the PSU and it works, and I've also tried powering on the motherboard with only the CPU and one stick of RAM, but it's the same result every time. Any insight to this would be hugely appreciated, I have no idea what to do and am not experience with building systems.

Comment: Are you trying to turn on your machine without any sort of cooler on your CPU per your second screenshot? When I had this problem on my own build (turning the power to the motherboard resulted in a big fact nothing happening) it turned out the fault was with the motherboard. I suspect a similar issue. In my case it was a big fat short within the CPU socket.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get it started with no CPU cooling just to verify everything turns out. That wouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: "That wouldn't be a problem, right?" - Yes; The CPU would instantly overheat and automatically shutdown within seconds. If there is no fan connected to the CPU_FAN/CPU_PUMP header it could also fail to power on, although, I still suspect a problem with the motherboard/CPU

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think the CPU would overheat so quickly, thanks for the advice. I'm just hesitant to say motherboard failure because the bios light comes on, it seems like if it were really a mobo failure nothing would come on at all?

Comment: As explained earlier.  I had a motherboard with a short within the socket.  The standby power LED would turn on, I would attempt to turn on the system, and absolutely nothing happened.  I RMA'ed the motherboard and once everything was setup again everything worked.  So a fault in the socket and/or CPU would explain your issue. *If my personal experience with a very similar problem isn't helpful I understand.*

Comment: No, it's great! I'm sorry I just didn't understand at first